# How to display json url to html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am very slow in jquery, I tried to research regarding on how to display json file from url to html but it seems i didnt get the code. I just want to display this json data here: http://api.paperstreetjobs.com/exam/show/getProblems

I want to display to my html every question and difficulty value inside the array.

my json:

```
[
[
   {
    "id":26,"question":"What html element will the following CSS code selects?\r\n\r\nli:not(#foo) > fieldset > div > span > input[type='radio'], \r\nli:not(#foo) > fieldset > div > span > input[type='checkbox']",
    "note":"",
    "difficulty":"easy",
    "language":"css"
   }
],
[
   {
     "id":18,"question":"Try to figure out what is wrong with the codes below. Explain your answer\r\n\r\n",
     "note":"",
     "difficulty":"average",
     "language":"php"
   }
],
[
   {
     "id":112,
     "question":"Assuming there is a sample.json file inside your directory. That contains\r\n{\"1\":{\"id\":1,\"clicks\":100,\"stars\":5},\"2\":{\"id\":2,\"clicks\":120,\"stars\":2},\"3\":{\"id\":3,\"clicks\":60,\"stars\":3}}\r\n \r\nGet the value of the json file\r\nSort the values according to its \u201cstars\u201d descending and \u201cclicks\u201d descending.\r\nReplace the sample.json content to the sorted value assuming that the file is writable.\r\nAssuming that the values changes once a day, your code should adopt to the values of \u201cclicks\u201d and \u201cstars\u201d",
     "note":"",
     "difficulty":"hard",
     "language":"php"
   }
]
]
```

Pls help me and guide me. thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is callback code for complete ajax query:

```
var
    itemsBox = $('#items-box'),
    i;

for (i = 0; i < yourJSON[0].length; i++) {
    itemsBox.append(''
        + '<div>id: '         + yourJSON[i][0].id         + '</div>'
        + '<div>question: '   + yourJSON[i][0].question   + '</div>'
        + '<div>note: '       + yourJSON[i][0].note       + '</div>'
        + '<div>difficulty: ' + yourJSON[i][0].difficulty + '</div>'
        + '<div>language: '   + yourJSON[i][0].language   + '</div>'
    );
}
```

Comment: Hello sir, the json file is from http://api.paperstreetjobs.com/exam/show/getProblems how i gonna retrieve this to display?

Comment: oh i think i get it now sir, i put your code inside to this code `var myJson = "http://api.paperstreetjobs.app:8000/exam/show/getProblems";
                $.getJSON(myJson, function(result)`

Answer (score 2):

It's simple.

```
$.get( "http://api.paperstreetjobs.com/exam/show/getProblems", function( data ) {
  $( ".result" ).html( data );
  alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

you may use @Deep code to render it.

Best

Egor

Comment: yeah. thanks sir. @deep code was i looking for. using for loop! thanks for your help too!